# Fixing Sizing in Spritekit

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, sprite-kit, scale

I am creating an app in SpriteKit using C# on Xamarin, and I am trying to position "Tiles" correctly on a 1024x768 scene. Here is my code for the tiles.

```
     public class GameScene : SKScene
{
    Tile tile1 = new Tile(320, 320, UIColor.Blue);
    Tile tile2 = new Tile(320, 320, UIColor.Blue);
    Tile tile3 = new Tile(320, 320, UIColor.Blue);
    Tile tile4 = new Tile(320, 320, UIColor.Blue);
    public GameScene(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void DidMoveToView(SKView view)
    {




        tile1.numberOfTiles = 4;
        tile1.tileNumber = 1;
        tile1.setTilePosition();

        tile2.numberOfTiles = 4;
        tile2.tileNumber = 2;
        tile2.setTilePosition();

        tile3.numberOfTiles = 4;
        tile3.tileNumber = 3;
        tile3.setTilePosition();

        tile4.numberOfTiles = 4;
        tile4.tileNumber = 4;
        tile4.setTilePosition();

        this.AddChild(tile1.tile);
        this.AddChild(tile2.tile);
        this.AddChild(tile3.tile);
        this.AddChild(tile4.tile);

        Console.WriteLine(this.Frame.Size);
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {

    }

    public override void Update(double currentTime)
    {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

As you can see, the tiles are set to be 320, 320 in size. The positions are also set in the same ratio, which should be correct. However, this is the output in the simulator

[image]

As you can see, the tiles are way too big to fit on the screen, and the positions are incorrect. How would I solve this? If there is code needed to solve this, swift or c# are both ok. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That is doing exactly what you are coding.

- 1st

  you need to learn about aspect mode,  you are doing a 3:4 scene but trying to render it in a 9:16 device,  You have 4 choices:

> **.AspectFill:**  This is default in XCodes template and will scale the
> scene up to the farthest borders while maintaining aspect ratio.  This
> will result in cropping on the closer borders of the device in lieu of
> black borders on the farthest borders
>
> **.AspectFit:**  This will scale the scene up to the closest borders while
> maintaining aspect ratio.  This will result in black borders on the
> farthest borders of the device in lieu of cropping on the closer
> borders
>
> **.Fill:**  This will scale the scene on both sides, but will not retain
> aspect ratio, giving you no cropping or black borders, but will yield
> in distortion of images via a fatty or slimming effect
>
> **.ResizeFill:**  This will resize the scene coordinates to that of the
> view it is in.  This means there is no scaling, and on larger devices
> the sprites will appear smaller, with more visibility to the entire
> scenes contents.

- 2nd:

  You need to understand that the default origin for the scene is the bottom left corner, while all children inside the scene have it in the center.  When plotting your points, you need to take this into effect.

Now from what I am seeing here, you have `.ResizeFill` going on, and you are assuming origin of the scene is bottom left.  So what is happening is your scene is getting resized to that of the IPhone 5,  and due to this resize,  your tiles are now off location because the center of the scene changed from the point (512,384) to point (160,284) meaning you need to ass/subtract less than you would on the phone as you would the iPad.

My suggestion is to use `.AspectFill` for a `ScaleMode`, and to set the scenes `AnchorPoint` to (0.5,0.5)

Comment: Actually seems like what you told me recently apple is doing now by default, which is setting scene anchor to 0.5 0.5. I am actually starting to like anchor 0.5 0.5, before I preferred 0, 0. They however also changed the scene default size to iPhone 6/7 resolution which makes no sense for a universal game.

Comment: @crashoverride777 why wouldn't it make sense?  Those are your device sizes now,  iphone 5 is old

Comment: The default setting before was 768*1024. The new settings is 750*1334 which makes no sense when you are trying to make a universal game that runs on iPads as well.

Comment: With the old setting you had more screen estate on iPads at the top/bottom (landscape) or left/right (portrait) which made perfect sense as the iPad is not proper widescreen. That area you just cover with extra background. If you use the new default settings that is reversed where you suddenly have more screen estate on the left/right (landscape) and top/bottom (portrait) which makes no sense.

Comment: Why wouldnt it?  You give the best quality to the most users,  and other devices scale.

Comment: see my comment I just posted when you replied.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to make an iPad app, not a universal LOL

Comment: 9 out of 10 times your scale mode will be aspect fill,  with aspect fill on an ipad you lose the top and bottom, which is better to design for than having to lose the sides when going from ipad to iphone

Comment: In landscape games in iPad you should have more screen estate at the top and bottom. So on iPhone you loose that which makes perfect sense. Now its the other way around with the new default scene resolution settings.

Comment: now that extra screen estate is on the left and right in landscape.

Comment: What? You are missing the point,  you are not making an iPad app, you are making a universal app.   Iphone 6 is where you put your best quality at, since that is most devices now being used.  Your iPad should be scaling.  The issue now becomes a 16:9 and a 4:3 concern,  it is easier to design a 16:9 area with the focus parts in a 4:3 area then it is to design a 4:3 area with a 16:9 focus area

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125412/discussion-between-crashoverride777-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: The cropping happens on left and right on ipad in landscape,  before it never cropped

Comment: Exactly, before it never cropped on iPads. Now it crops on the left and right which makes no sense. Chat? Ill show you